# Not displaying DetailDisclosureButton inside annotated view

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3, mkmapviewdelegate

We are trying to implement MKMapView in iOS application.I got the mapView with the given locations and pins.When I tap on these pins I am getting the title and subtitle also.Now I want to include a detail Disclosure button in this view in which the title and subtitle are displayed.For that I used the below given code[MKPinannotation detail disclosure button - present new view is going inside the first method but it is not showing the detailDisclosureButton.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"] autorelease];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped
{
}
```

Now what can I do?Anyone please take a look and help me...

Comment: Once try this MKPinAnnotationView *pinView declare in .h file and use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != map.userLocation) 
    {
        NSString *defaultPinID =@"com.invasivecode.pin1";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        UIButton *btnGo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [btnGo addTarget:self action:@selector(goToLocation:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnGo;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.draggable=NO;
    } 
    else {
        [map.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

**Declare this in .h file**

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView
```

Comment: : Hi Manohar, Now I have another problem.When the map is getting loaded for the second time,it doesnt display the pins.Please help me to find a solution.I have posted the question with code in the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297158/annotated-pins-are-not-getting-loaded-during-reloading-of-map?noredirect=1#comment23330064_16297158

Answer (score 0):

please try setting the frame for rightButton i.e

```
rightButton.frame = CGRectMAke (x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: No need to set the Frame dear

Comment: how can u add anything without a frame .

Comment: pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView this automatically takes the View... No need to set the frame

Comment: the plz post ur answer and enlighten us

Comment: When you are assigning some Property to already existing property then you no need to set the frame